# Angularjs setting ionicon at a specific interval in a list

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building an Ionic application and on my template I have a list in which I want to populate single ionicons at a specific interval(say each 2 seconds) one at a time from a list of ionicons I have defined in my controller.

**My controller:**

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.ionicon_class_list1=['ion-xbox','ion-ribbon-a', 'ion-trophy', 'ion-ios-football','ion-android-bicycle'];
  $scope.ionicon_class_list2=['ion-wrench','ion-scissors', 'ion-gear-b', 'ion-ios-alarm-outline','ion-ios-flask'];
  $scope.ionicon_class_list3=['ion-edit','ion-clipboard', 'ion-calculator', 'ion-printer','ion-android-calendar'];

  $scope.current_symbol_for_list1 = '';


  for(symbol in $scope.ionicon_class_list1){

      /* logic to select symbol at a specific time interval */
  }

  $scope.setSymbol = function(symbol){

    $scope.current_symbol_for_list1=symbol

  }

})
```

**My HTML:**

```
<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content class="padding">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col col1" align="center">

            <i class="icon {{current_symbol_for_list1}}"></i>

      </div>

      <div class="col col2" align="center">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item ng-repeat="symbol in ionicon_class_list2">
            <i class="icon {{symbol}}"></i>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </div>

      <div class="col col3" align="center">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item ng-repeat="symbol in ionicon_class_list3">
            <i class="icon {{symbol}}"></i>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div align="center">
      <button class="button button-dark">Start</button>
    </div>


  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

How can I do it? Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/eYKQPM?p=preview

**NOTE**: When I click 'Start' a single Ionicon will appear in each of the three columns (initially columns are empty) for 2 seconds and then it will change.

Answer (score 0):

**In controller I added:**

```
 var i = 0, length = $scope.ionicon_class_list1.length;
  $scope.iterator = function(){

    console.log($scope.ionicon_class_list1[i]);
    $scope.current_symbol_for_list1=$scope.ionicon_class_list1[i]


    if(++i<length) {

      $timeout($scope.iterator, 3000)

    }

  }
})
```

**In HTML:**
on Start button

```
ng-click="iterator()"
```